# How to adjust bar button item width from IB or programmaticaly?

Tags: ios7, uitoolbar

I create a UIToolbar with IB , and setup it as inputAccessoryView of one TextFiled. But I don't know how to adjust the width of bar button item and textfield width added in that toolbar.

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
  {

  textField.inputAccessoryView=self.toolbarForChat;
  return YES;
  }

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

No you can't change the width of bar button item.you can use UIButton instead of  bar button item in toolbar.